# Best way to do async programming with Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, node.js, asp.net-web-api, signalr

There seems to be several options available at the moment to do async/push-style programming with asp.net. But I'm a little confused as to what is the best and what offers the most developer friendly approach. Things I've already come across are,

NodeJs

SignalR

[Using PushStreamContent (Web API) and something like KnockoutJS](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/native-html5-push-notifications-with-asp-net-web-api-and-knockout-js/)

Though [SignalR is deemed to make it to asp.net 4.5](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudio11BetaInContext.aspx), I see a lot of interest on NodeJs   [within MS](http://adtmag.com/articles/2012/01/26/guthrie-talks-node.aspx) (Specially around Azure). Can anyone shed some light on the differences  (of at least NodeJs and SignalR) ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

SignalR is "a client and server side library for .NET that provides messaging and an abstraction over a persistent connection." This doesn't magically make your code async - it just allows your server to call clients (including JavaScript running in your users' browsers) asynchronously.

However, C# 5.0 which ships in .NET 4.5 & Visual Studio 2012 (as well as in [Mono](http://mono-project.com/) 2.11+) allows you to write/modify code to be async through the use of the new `async` & `await` keywords.

If you're already a .NET developer, C# async & await and SignalR are very easy to pick-up, learn and run, allowing you to build highly scalable, very high performance systems.

Node.js enables you to write your code in JavaScript and host it in an app server.

Node is getting a lot of attention at the moment but if you're coming from a .NET development background, it's worth noting some of the things that may surprise/annoy you when moving to JavaScript on the server:

1. JavaScript is a very powerful and extremely flexible dynamically typed language. However, this flexibility can be very dangerous and problematic until you've learned its many flaws and how to overcome them. If you MUST execute JavaScript code, consider writing your source in languages like [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) and [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) which compile down to JavaScript but insulate you from a lot of JavaScript's dangers.
2. While node offers great async dispatch capabilities, its code-execution performance can be FAR slower than executing C#. If your code does little/no processing of data, you may not notice this issue. If, however, your code does a fair amount of data-processing / calculations / analysis / etc., you may find node's JavaScript performance-hit unacceptable.
3. Node is single-threaded! If your code has to perform some heavy processing, for example, performing a complex calculation over a large amount of data, it'll prevent a single node instance from serving other incoming requests until each processing operation is complete. Thus, you will need to plan on enabling [node clustering](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) (currently an experimental feature) or, **if you host node on Windows**, use IIS & IISNode][4](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) which handles node instance management using the (awesome) IIS & Windows Process Activation infrastructure.
4. Compared to the typical .NET developer's debugging experience, debugging code running under node is a slow and cumbersome process right now. To do so requires you to use node-inspector and Chrome web browser to debug the code, but the experience is poor: Breakpoints aren't preserved across runs; conditional breakpoints are not supported; the displayed call stack is shallow; etc.

Comment: Decent list, but there are a couple glaring problems. The V8 javascript engine is fast. It's very fast actually. There are certain use cases where C# is faster, and believe it or not, some where javascript excels (regex). Regardless, none of this is likely to be an issue one way or another in a web application as code execution for pretty much any language these days is *fast enough*. The other issue is talking about javascript being function. While that is true, you damn well better be writing code in a functional manner in C# too if you are using SignalR an Async.

Comment: And yes, I agree... javascript tools suck right now, especially when you're used to Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm gonna stick with SignalR it seems. Nevertheless, gotta try node sometime. Tkx for the detailed answer!

Comment: @Timothy: Performance is NEVER to be ignored. This is especially true of today's $100+ per month per 2-cores/instance cloud services! Employing the wrong technology can result in HUGE cost overheads. I've seen situations where using node would triple the cost of a .NET service for the same level of perf!

Comment: @RichardTurner I would love to have a more in depth conversation on this point because I don't know that I agree at all. If performance were a critical factor for most web apps, Ruby on Rails and to a lesser extent PHP would not exist, and there would be no successful startups using these technologies. Clearly that is not the case, so there must be more important factors than execution speed when determining your platform. I would also argue that if someone built something in Node that required 3x the hardware for equivalent perf, to a .NET solution, they are using Node wrong.

Comment: @Timothy: Happy to discuss if you'd like to. Most web apps don't get enough traffic to make any difference and can happily live on a shared host to be woken up twice a day to serve a couple of requests. But reality is reality. Twice the cost for operations is twice the cost. Period. Some startup may have enough cash to pay 2-3 x the cost to operate their sites. I'd rather spend my cash more carefully.

Comment: What about PushStreamContent web api? Which amongst three would be better for a scenario where we need to do a playback or visualization of the simulation, reading from a dump file, and user having freedom to navigate through the timeline as he desires (just like video buffering)?

Comment: @Anunay: PushStreamContent is a powerful tool (see http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/native-html5-push-notifications-with-asp-net-web-api-and-knockout-js/) and can certainly be used to provide streaming capabilities. Depending on your needs, however, SignalR may provide additional, potentially more scalable, capabilities.

Comment: Few pointers needed for SignalR. I got hands on the examples for streaming data, but I want to have some feature like video playback, with controls to stop start navigate and hold streaming if i have enough data on client. Problem for me right now is to have these controls on streaming.

Comment: @AnunaySinha Stream control is best achieved by making calls against your service to start streaming from different points in the dataset, asjust flow rate, etc.